# How can I turn a list-group into a dropdown menu with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am working with the lastest version of Bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to make my 'list-group' responsive. I've been looking for different solutions but I couldn't find anything I could apply to my problem.

My 'list-group' is supposed to be a tab, with its content showed on the left. While on desktop it works perfectly, it's not well designed for the mobile and, while looking for a solution, I realized that a dropdown menu shown on the top of the content would have worked. I have no clue how to 'convert' my list into a dropdown without breaking it tho.

This is how it looks now, red background for the selected tab and a different red for when hovered: [list-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfzsQ.png). I'd love to move it on the top of its content when on mobile view, so when I click on the title of the category, I can expand its submenu.

The code is this:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 ">
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-tab" role="tablist">

        <h4> Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        </br>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-who-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-who" role="tab" aria-controls="who">dolor sit amet quo te</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-info-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-info" role="tab" aria-controls="info">lorem prompta deseruisse</a>
        </br>
        <h4> Mei ipsum neglegentur ex</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-contact-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact">est probo</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-where-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-where" role="tab" aria-controls="where">nusquam eu</a>
        </br>
        <h4> Quo solum soleat</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-get-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-get" role="tab" aria-controls="get">adversarium id</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-send-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-send" role="tab" aria-controls="send">qui ex minim discere</a>

    </div>
  </div>
```

So basically when on small screens like mobile/tablet, my whole list should go on the top of the tab, converting the 'h4' into a dropdown menu and once it's clicked, it shows the respective item.

Maybe creating a dropdown menu only for small screens can do the trick, but I'm not sure if it can be considered as a real solution or more like a bad shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your list group into a dropdown is fairly straight forward. What we want to end up with is similar to the [dropdown menu with headers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#menu-content) in the documentation.

First we get rid of the `list-group-flush` and all the `list-group-item-action` class entries. Next we rename `list-group` to `dropdown`:

```
  <div class="col-xl-3 ">
      <div class="dropdown" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <h4> Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item active" id="list-who-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-who" role="tab" aria-controls="who">dolor sit amet quo te</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-info-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-info" role="tab" aria-controls="info">lorem prompta deseruisse</a>
        </br>
        <h4> Mei ipsum neglegentur ex</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-contact-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact">est probo</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-where-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-where" role="tab" aria-controls="where">nusquam eu</a>
        </br>
        <h4> Quo solum soleat</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-get-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-get" role="tab" aria-controls="get">adversarium id</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-send-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-send" role="tab" aria-controls="send">qui ex minim discere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now the first `dropdown` or `class="dropdown"` needs to become `class="dropdown-menu show"` and we are going to add a class to the `h4` headings namely: `class="dropdown-header"`.

```
  <div class="col-xl-3 ">
      <div class="dropdown-menu show" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <h4 class="dropdown-header"> Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item active" id="list-who-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-who" role="tab" aria-controls="who">dolor sit amet quo te</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-info-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-info" role="tab" aria-controls="info">lorem prompta deseruisse</a>
        </br>
        <h4 class="dropdown-header"> Mei ipsum neglegentur ex</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-contact-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact">est probo</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-where-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-where" role="tab" aria-controls="where">nusquam eu</a>
        </br>
        <h4 class="dropdown-header"> Quo solum soleat</h4>
        </br>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-get-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-get" role="tab" aria-controls="get">adversarium id</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="list-send-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-send" role="tab" aria-controls="send">qui ex minim discere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That is all that needs to change for a list group to become a dropdown menu, the rest can remain as is.

nJoy!

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort you put into this! The result is less appealing than expected tho, it's so disappointing! The list is too long to just keep it like that, do you think it's a good idea if I use 2 menu, one for the desktop and something like a collapsed menu or an accordion (so I can open only one collapsed item as the same time)? I've been looking for these kind of solutions and they look so nice, especially the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list-group div covers 3 out of 12 column on a large screen, Why don't you try putting col-sm-12?

Comment: That's the first thing I thought about right after asking the question. The problem is that the result is not nice as expected, since the list is kinda long and a mobile user would have to scroll a lot before reading what got selected. I'm looking for a more comfortable solution as a collapsed menu or even better an accordion. Is it a good idea to just have 2 different list, one for the deskop and one for smaller devices?